# Why does reportviewer 10 render reports so slowly?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I've noticed there's a HUGE difference in the rendering time between reportviewers 9 and 10 in favor of 9. 10 seems to be at least 10 times slower. Has anyone had any experience in tweaking things to fix reportviewer 10? Using Local mode btw.

Thanks.

Isaac

Comment: You are the first to complain about it.  Run it on another machine.

Comment: I have a fancy report with subreports and groupings and even on an I7 really big reports take exponentially longer it seems.

Comment: Exponentially longer than reportviewer 9 used to...

Comment: I actually had to revert to reportviewer 9 for the time being. It's not fun having to edit the rdlc files in vs2008 while the main project is in vs 2010. At least its forcing me to learn how to edit the raw xml.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if its because of the service pack, but now the only reports that render slowly are the ones with subreports in them.

Comment: I've since solved the subreport problem. I think the key is not to do any database querying in the subreport event handler. Have all your ducks in a row beforehand: Just pass enough information to the subreport to filter the already calculated report results to what that particular subreport needs

Answer (score 0):

I am having terrible problems with speed and VS2010 with firefox.

IE is instant and there is an awful lag with firefox. I noticed this question as I was writing rdlc reports at the time.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. But you should use the comment feature for these. Use the answer part for actual answers.